# Cross-Browser Image Grayscale with CSS

Tags: css

Grayscale Effect doesnot work well in firefox so for alternative i am using.

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
```

But After applying this css,firefox show me error could not load the image.
I am applying this effect in revolution slider where Any no of images can be there.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: actually i am testing this on revolution slider in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I had the same problem and found it on their developer site and it worked for me:

```
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Here's a link to their site for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter